# How to increment the value of initialized variable in mongodb query and that initialized value variable I am using to fetch data from object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I increment the value of initialized variable in mongodb?

```
    var FeedbackObj = {
"content": [{
        "feed": "It was interesting",
        "emotion": "interesting"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was cool",
        "emotion": "cool"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was amazing",
        "emotion": "amazing"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was fantastic",
        "emotion": "fantastic"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was entertaining",
        "emotion": "entertaining"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was superb",
        "emotion": "superb"
    }
]}

db.Movies.aggregate([

{"$group":{_id:{content_title:"$content_title",trailer_id:'$trailer_id'}}},
{"$project":{_id:0,content_title:"$_id.content_title",trailer_id:"$_id.trailer_id"}}

]).forEach(function(x){
    let i = 0 ;
    var y = {};
    y.contentTitle = x.content_title;
    y.feedbackEmoji = "";
    y.feedbackText = FeedbackObj.content[i].feed;
    y.emotion = FeedbackObj.content[i].emotion;
    y.sentiment = 1.0;
    y.timestamp = new NumberLong(new Date().getTime());
    y.userID = "abc@mail.com"; 
    y.traileID = y.trailer_id;
    console.log("value of i :" + i +" : " + FeedbackObj.content[i].feed +" : " + FeedbackObj.content[i].emotion);
    i = parseInt(i)+1;
    if(i == 5){
        i = 0;
    }
    //db.User_Feedback.save(y);
})
```

Above i have initialized variable "i" and later i want to increase its value in every iteration but it's not working . Every time in console it's printing value for 0 index from above FeedbackObj object .

Comment: i got solved :) . It was failing because of silly mistake .

Comment: Then please answer your own question and show us where the error was. Imagine you saw a thread with the exact same problem and the person who posted it just said "Nevermind, solved it"

Comment: @MechMK1 i had initialized variable "i" inside the for loop , that's why it was reflecting every time to its initial value .

Comment: Please write an actual answer below your question (where you would normally answer any question). You can answer your own questions and it's not considered bad form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer

```
    var FeedbackObj = {
"content": [{
        "feed": "It was interesting",
        "emotion": "interesting"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was cool",
        "emotion": "cool"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was amazing",
        "emotion": "amazing"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was fantastic",
        "emotion": "fantastic"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was entertaining",
        "emotion": "entertaining"
    },
    {
        "feed": "It was superb",
        "emotion": "superb"
    }]}

  let i = 0 ;

db.Movies.aggregate([
{$match :{imdb_rating:{$gt:9}}},
{"$group":{_id:{content_title:"$content_title",trailer_id:'$trailer_id'}}},
{"$project":{_id:0,content_title:"$_id.content_title",trailer_id:"$_id.trailer_id"}}

])
forEach(function(x){
    var y = {};
    y.contentTitle = x.content_title;
    y.feedbackEmoji = "";
    y.feedbackText = FeedbackObj.content[i].feed;
    y.emotion = FeedbackObj.content[i].emotion;
    y.sentiment = 1.0;
    y.timestamp = new NumberLong(new Date().getTime());
    y.userID = "vikash.srivastava@mailinator.com"; 
    y.trailerID = x.trailer_id;
    console.log("value of i :" + i +" : " + FeedbackObj.content[i].feed +" : " + FeedbackObj.content[i].emotion+" : " + x.trailer_id);
    i++;
    if(i == 6){
        i = 0;
    }
   db.User_Feedback.save(y);
})
```